# Puppet Postgresql Error

Tags: puppet

I apply an incremental change to my postgresql install using puppet.

```
sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/vagrant/puppet/modules -e "include iwd-postgresql"
```

This result in the following error:

```
Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class postgresql::globals at /vagrant/puppet/modules/iwd-postgresql/manifests/init.pp:6 on node target.intware.com
Wrapped exception:
Could not find declared class postgresql::globals
```

I have installed the puppetlabs/postgresql module.

If I do a puppet list I see the following:

```
[vagrant@target ~]$ puppet module list
    /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules
    ├── puppetlabs-apt (v2.2.0)
    ├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.2.4)
    ├── puppetlabs-postgresql (v4.6.0)
    └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.9.0)
```

/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)

Any ideas?  I am running the appply command on a vagrant virtual machine in vagrant's home folder.

Comment: What is in `/vagrant/puppet/modules`?

Comment: @ChrisPitman, I've put the output of a puppet modules list in the question.

Comment: Why are you setting the modulepath when you run `puppet apply` but not when you list modules?

Comment: @ChrisPitman, I was setting the modulepath like that because that is where my dev team has defined their puppet resources.  But your comment pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ChrisPitman's comments pointed me in the right direction.  I needed to set up the correct modulepath to include both our custom modules along with pre-built ones.

The following worked for me:

```
sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/vagrant/puppet/modules:/etc/puppet/modules -e "include iwd-postgresql"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used the command `puppet apply` you was using this path `/home/vagrant/puppet/modules`, but your module is installed under `/home/vagrant/.puppet/modules`, anyway If you are using `vagrant`, I think is better if you the `Vagrantfile` for use puppet and customize your vm